# readr::read_rds() function saved in older version of R

Tags: r

I save my work in .rds format and now, I can't read my files. I get the error:

```
matriz_1 <- readr::read_rds(here("foo", "matriz_1.rds")) and 

matriz_1 <- readr::write_rds(here("foo", "matriz_1.rds"))
```

> Error in readRDS(path) : ReadItem: unknown type 0, perhaps written by later version of R.

I'm using R version `4.0`. Can I use another function to access these data?

Using the new function `infoRDS()` I get this information

```
$version
[1] 3

$writer_version
[1] "3.6.0"

$min_reader_version
[1] "3.5.0"

$format
[1] "xdr"

$native_encoding
[1] "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Please show your `saveRDS` and `readRDS` code.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. I did get the error anymore and I'll use the base function now.

Comment: There should be no problem reading older rds files, especially from R 3.6.  It sounds more likely that your data got corrupted somehow.  The error message indicates that it tried to read an R object of "type = 0" which is impossible in any version.

Comment: I can read the data without problems now. I don't know whats happens, but thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Normally you shouldn't have a problem to read older `.rds`-saved files. You can use `saveRDS()` to write the older (R 1.4.0 - R 3.5.0) or the current version by specifying the `version =` argument. `readRDS()` can read both.

```
tmp = tempfile()
saveRDS(iris, tmp) # stores in new version
readRDS(tmp)
readr::read_rds(tmp)

saveRDS(iris, tmp, version = 2) # stores in version used frim R 1.4.0 to R 3.5.0
readRDS(tmp)
readr::read_rds(tmp)
```

Personally, I would refrain from using `readr::write_rds()` or `readr::read_rds()` because these functions add nothing new apart from some confusion and having different names.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use readRDS. Today I worked without any error in this sense even with readr::read_rds. and without change nothing in my code